# What is the difference between a tear strap and a doubler?

Tags: aircraft-structures

Is there a difference between a tear strap and a doubler? If I get it right, the tear strap reinforce the main structure locally and prevent the propagation of tears, while the doubler, well, it has the same function. Is the difference lying in their geometry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is the doubler has a broader application, as a general reinforcement of a skin, web, or flange to increase tensile strength, compression strength or stiffness by making the part thicker over an area, generally with multiple load paths to absorb.

A tear strap, being a "strap", is more targeted as a tension-only reinforcement that is applied along a particular load axis to offload some of the tension load on the underlying part along that axis.

Comment: The narrower section of the strap is able to reinforce a targeted path, it makes sense.
Just one question on the other part of the answer: 
If the strap increases the tensile strength, shouldn't it be able to improve compression strength and stiffness as well? Or its installation procedure it's not the same as the one used to install a doubler, so somehow it influences the final function of the strap?

Comment: Somewhat, but If it was intended to improve compression strength as well, it will have a cross section more optimized for stiffness and buckling resistance, like a hat section or U channel or something.  A strap being a thin (relatively) strip of metal will contribute little resistance to buckling of a panel for a given amount of material and would be a very inefficient way to add compression strength, pound for pound.